# Case-insensitive count duplicate line, remove duplicate by choose case with highest duplicate

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

The duplicate is combination of different case text.

I need to count number of duplicate (case-insensitive) and then I need to remove duplicate by choose case with highest duplicate.

Below example:

```
hot chocolate
hot chocolate
hot chocolate
Hot Chocolate
Hot Chocolate
Hot Chocolate
Hot Chocolate
Hot Chocolate
Xicolatada
Xicolatada
Xicolatada
Xicolatada
XICOLATADA
XICOLATADA
```

Should become:

```
Hot Chocolate, 8
Xicolatada, 6
```

This question similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447473/linux-command-or-script-counting-duplicated-lines-in-a-text-file) but I need to choose case with highest duplicate and count case-insensitively.

Comment: Just curious, has anyone here ever needed to search for a string but only return whichever version of that string has the most instances based on case?!? this just seems like purely academic hoops that people are made to jump through in school and maybe would never, ever be needed in the real world!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

And there's `uniq --ignore-case --count | sort --numeric --reverse`:

```
sort | uniq -ic /tmp/foo.txt | sort -nr
      8 hot chocolate
      6 Xicolatada
```

And to switch around the order putting a comma in there add this pipe onto the end:

```
... | sed -e 's/^ *\([0-9]*\) \(.*\)/\2, \1/'
```

See the first comment below as to why we have the leading sort.

Comment: This is definitely working fine for this example. However it's worth noting that uniq filters only adjacent matching lines according to its man page.  If there would be another hot chocolate at the end it would count it as a unique occurence. This might be an important info for readers like me...

Comment: Ok, I added another sort at the beginning to account for this.

Answer (score 5):

I would use `tolower()` to make all the items lowercase. Then it is a matter of storing them in an array `a[]` and then printing the results:

```
$ awk '{a[tolower($0)]++} END {for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' file
xicolatada 6
hot chocolate 8
```

To have the output in comma-separated format, add `-v OFS=,`.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you your desired output

```perl
use List::Util qw(sum);

my %count;
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    $count{+lc}{$_}++; 
}

$,=", ";
$\="\n";

while (my ($key, $hash) = each %count) {
    my @labels = reverse 
                 map  { $_->[0] }
                 sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] } 
                 map  { [ $_, $hash->{$_} ] } 
                 keys %$hash;
    my $sum = sum values %$hash;

    print $labels[0], $sum;
}
```

Then

```
$ perl count.pl data.txt 
Hot Chocolate, 8
Xicolatada, 6
```

The order of the output is indeterminate.

Comment: You can use `$b->[1] <=> $a->[1]` to sort reverse, so we can drop `reverse`.

Comment: I find that less readable: the sort block already contains sufficient magic.

Answer (score 0):

If that list of items is in a file named `list.txt`, you can do:

```
tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' < list.txt | sort | uniq -c
```

...which will output:

```
8 hot chocolate
6 xicolatada
```

Answer (score 0):

POSIXly:

```
<in dd conv=lcase|LC_ALL=C sort|uniq -c >out
```

...which prints...

```
8 hot chocolate
6 xicolatada
```

Or with GNU tools:

```
<in LC_ALL=C sort -f|uniq -ic >out
```

...which prints...

```
8 Hot Chocolate
6 XICOLATADA
```

You need a GNU `uniq` there - or, well, you need one which supports the case `-i`nsensitive option, anyhow. All `sort`s should do that with `-f` anyway.

Comment: @cuonglm - is there any solution offered here which wouldn't need an explicit locale edited in? With the sample input given though, this one doesn't.

Comment: Yeah, all current answer need. The locale is for strictness. Feel free to revert it.

Comment: @cuonglm - nah. better is better. It's faster, anyway. So you know, `uniq` has the same problem.

Comment: GNU `uniq` does but POSIX `uniq` doesn't. GNU `uniq -i` using byte comparison instead of collation order so doesn't have.

Comment: @cuonglm - I upvoted that comment - but maybe in haste? I don't read that anywhere in the [spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/uniq.html#). It doesn't seem to specify anywhere *how* the lines should be compared, only that they should be.

Comment: [This thread](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.standards.posix.austin.general/10517/focus=10527) may helps.

Comment: @cuonglm - yeah, I've read that one. It's why I mentioned `uniq` having the same problem. As I recall they just go back and forth a lot about it, but different historical versions are discussed which may or may not do it that way.

Comment: @cuonglm: *For uniq, I would leave the behaviour unspecified as using `strcoll()` would make more sense for consistency with sort `-u`, `comm` and `join` and to be able to work on the output of `sort` **(which it's generally used to)**, but many implementations use `strcmp()`.
---
I think there are pros and cons of both types of implementation.
Perhaps for Issue 8 we should add an option to choose between them. It might also make sense to add something to `sort` to allow specifying that any identical lines in the output must be adjacent.*